# LWC, Is there a way to programmatically check if a lightning-input-field is in error?

Tags: lightning-inputfield

I'm using lightning-record-edit-form and lightning-input-field so that I get entries fields that understand the basic metadata, like getting the picklists automatically and making fields required.  But I want to do all the processing in code rather than have the form submit via LDS.  THere's a bunch of processing including callouts I need to do and other updates all done in Apex and it's better to update the record there and simply tell the object on the page to refresh.

I will be really useful to requery the state of the fields to see if any are in error, then skip processing if any are.  I see a "setErrors" method in the documentation ( although it says reserved for internal use) but I don't see any "getErrors" method.

Anyone know for a way to get all the lightning-input-field to see if any are in error?

Comment: The documentation is so thin, it seems one always has to rely on forums and just trying stuff.  I think the below may do what I want.  This is for one field.  of course a querySelectorAll and then an iteration could check all fields....

let someFieldEl = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="someField"]');
let someFieldElValid = someFieldEl.reportValidity();
if (!someFieldElValid) {
    return;
}